# Mkdocs eliminate copy paste in files

Tags: markdown, readme, mkdocs

Can I somehow include a file into a file in mkdocs?
I do not want to copy paste the same sections again and again.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including one document in another is not a Markdown feature, and currently MkDocs only does Markdown processing on Markdown documents. Therefore, at this time there is no way to do this with MkDocs.

Interestingly, it does not even appear that anyone has made such a feature request. There is the pending feature to make various variables available to be displayed within a Markdown page (see issue [#304](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/issues/304)), but no mention is made there of including other documents. That said, depending on the solution chosen, its possible that if/when the issue is addressed it will also provide for the ability to include other pages.

Either way, if/when a Plugin API is added (see issue [#206](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/issues/206)) you should be able to do any prepossessing of your own which would include running the Markdown text through a template system which support "including" pages before the Markdown is parsed. In fact, I expect that if you were to make a feature request, the answer would be to punt it to a Plugin.

Comment: I found a solution for this which markdown_include project: https://github.com/cmacmackin/markdown-include

Answer (score 6):

@doktoric is correct: to set the record straight, **there is a solution in MkDocs for including external files**, which involves using the [markdown-include extension](https://github.com/cmacmackin/markdown-include).

The syntax is the following:

```
{!filename.md!}
```

The procedure for achieving this is:

1. Install the extension according to the instructions (`pip install markdown-include`)
2. Modify the `mkdocs.yml` file, to register this extension for your website [sees explanations](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/configuration/#formatting-options), and below.
3. Start using the syntax extension in your markdown files.

In the `mkdocs.yml`file:

```
    markdown_extensions:
        include
```

---

#### Update (September 2020)

The solution I would suggest at this stage is through [mkdocs-macros plugin](https://mkdocs-macros-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#including-snippets-in-pages) (which I wrote). The plugin implements a jinja2 template engine, which means that [the `{% include ... %}` statement is available out of the box](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#include):

```
## Paragraph
{% include 'snippet.md' %}
```

Just install the plugin, declare it in `mkdocs.yml`, and you are good to go.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work at all. Not only is the above syntax wrong, but nothing seems to work that I have tried

Comment: Ok... I got it working. You need to use pip2 as this extension is pretty old

Comment: As a shameless plug, you might want to look at this exention that I wrote? https://github.com/fralau/mkdocs_macros_plugin

Comment: At the time of writing this comment, while using [mkdocs-material](https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material) - you should use this syntax:
`markdown_include.include` (instead of just `include`)

Comment: [markdown-include extension](https://github.com/cmacmackin/markdown-include) seems to do exactly (and only) what is requested here. Unfortunately, it has not been updated for a year at this point.